# "Over the years, I've improved [ON] my writing quality"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, phrase-meaning

1. Over the years, I've improved my writing quality.
2. Over the years, I've improved **on** my writing quality.

A) Are both sentences grammatically correct?

B) My understanding is the first sentence means that the speaker's writing quality has improved, whereas the second one means the speaker's writing quality has improved with respect to how it was before. Am I wrong in my understanding of these sentences?

C) Also, wouldn't the first sentence sound better if the word "quality" was ommitted?

Comment: There is no "fixed" preposition for your context, so ***both*** examples are fine - but so would be *...I've improved **in** my writing quality.* Google Books has [many written instances](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+has+improved+in+his%22) of *He has improved **in** his [ability to do something, his studies, his work,...]*. And I'm quite happy with *My wife has improved **with** her cooking since we've been married.* In your cited context, it makes no difference which preposition you use (if any), or if you append ***quality*** (or, say, ***ability***) after ***writing***.

Comment: Personally, I think the only "valid" part of this question is the matter of which preposition to use (Answer: there are several possibilities, including ***none***). Everything else is Off Topic writing advice.

Answer (score 2):

I think *improved* is better in your use. In both examples, your writing is better than it was.

As to *quality*, it might be better to omit it or to say it like this:
I've improved the quality of my writing.

To clarify, I think *improve on* suggests a fixed beginning of the comparison, for example,
We improved on last years score.
or
The new model improves on the advances achieved in the last product.

If you are continually improving something, I think simple *improve* is better.

Comment: I think the difference is that to improve something is to make it better, while to improve _on_ it is to replace it with something better (a higher score than last time, a new way of doing something...). So I consider (1) to be preferable (or, better still, Jack's version).

Comment: I just posted an addition to my answer as your comment came through; I agree completely.